# Migrate data between two SQL databases with identity column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is the scenario... I've two databases (A & B) with same schema but different records. I'd like to transfer `B's` data into corresponding tables in DB `A`.

Lets say we have tables named `Question` and `Answer` in both databases. DB `A` contains 10 records in `Question` table and 30 in `Answer` table. Both tables have identity column `Id` starting with 1(& auto increment), and there is 1 to many relation between `Question` and `Answer`.

In DB `B`, we have 5 entries in `Question` table and 20 in `Answer`.

My requirement is to copy data of both tables from source DB `B` into destination DB `A` without having any conflict in identity column while maintaining the relation between two tables during data transfer.

Any solution or potential workaround would be highly appreciated.

Comment: generate insert scripts and execute in required dbs

Comment: You really should provide some details about your table. [Here](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) is a great place to start.

Answer (score 2):

I will not write SQL here but here is what I think can be done. Make sure to use Identity insert ON and OFF.

1. Take maxids of both tables from DB A like `A_maxidquestion` and `A_maxidanswer`.
2. Select from B_question . In select column add derived col `QuestionID+A_maxidquestion`.This will be your new ID.
3. Select from B_Answer . In select column add derived col `AnswerID+A_maxidanswer` and fk id as `QuestionID+A_maxidquestion`.

Note- Make sure Destination table is not beeing used by any other process for inserting values while you are inserting

Comment: This is pretty brittle. What happens if there are other people in the system at the time these inserts are running?

Comment: SeanLange - yes that can be possible but it was mentioned its a migration though I have added note.

Answer (score 0):

One of the best approaches to something like this is to use the OUTPUT clause. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 You can insert the new parent and capture the newly inserted identity value which you can use to insert the children.

You can do this set based if you also include a temp table which would hold the original identity value and the new identity value.

With no details of the tables that is the best I can do.